# How to walk through directory in Erlang to take only folders?

Tags: erlang

```
-module(tut).
-export([main/0]).

main() -> 

    folders("C:/Users/David/test/").
    

folders(PATH) ->
    {_,DD} = file:list_dir(PATH),
    A = [{H,filelib:is_dir(PATH ++ H)}|| H <-DD],
    % R is a list of all folders inside PATH
    R = [PATH++X|| {X,Y} <- A, Y =:= true],
    io:fwrite("~p~n", [R]),
    case R of
        [] -> ok;
        % How call again folders function with the first element of the list?
        % And save the result in some kind of structure 
    end.
```

Sorry for the beginner question, but I'm still new to Erlang. I would like to know how I can call the function again until saves the results in a kind of list, tuple or structure...

Like:

```
  [
    {"C:/Users/David/test/log", 
      {"C:/Users/David/test/log/a", "C:/Users/David/test/log/b"}},
    {"C:/Users/David/test/logb", 
      {"C:/Users/David/test/logb/1", "C:/Users/David/test/logb/2","C:/Users/David/test/logb/3"}},
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things:

1. These 2 calls can be simplified.

```
A = [{H,filelib:is_dir(PATH ++ H)}|| H <-DD],
R = [PATH++X|| {X,Y} <- A, Y =:= true],
```

into

```
A = [H || H <- DD, filelib:is_dir(PATH ++ H) =:= true],
```

2. In terms of representation, sub-folders should be in list format, not tuple. It will be difficult to work with if they were tuples.
   Sample structure: `{Folder, [Subfolder1, Subfolder2, ...]}`, where `SubfolderX` will have the same definition and structure, **recursively**.
3. Folders are like tree, so need to have recursive call here. Hope you are already familiar with the concept. Below is one way to do it using list comprehension - there are other ways anyway, e.g. by using `lists:foldl` function.

```
folders(PATH) ->
    {_, DD} = file:list_dir(PATH), 
    A = [H || H <- DD, filelib:is_dir(PATH ++ "/" ++ H) =:= true],
    %%io:format("Path: ~p, A: ~p~n", [Path, A]), 
    case A of
        [] ->   %%Base case, i.e. folder has no sub-folders -> stop here
                {PATH, []}; 
         _ ->   %%Recursive case, i.e. folder has sub-folders -> call @folders
                {PATH, [folders(PATH ++ "/" ++ H2) || H2 <- A]}
    end.
```

For consistency reason, you need to call the main function **without** a forward slash at the end, as this will be added in the function itself.

```
Folders = folders("C:/Users/David/test"). %% <- without forward slash
```

A helper function `pretty_print` below can be used to visualize the output on the Erlang shell
Full code:

```
-export([folders/1]).
-export([main/0]).

main() -> 
    Folders = folders("C:/Users/David/test"),
    pretty_print(Folders, 0),
    ok.
    
folders(PATH) ->
    {_, DD} = file:list_dir(PATH), 
    A = [H || H <- DD, filelib:is_dir(PATH ++ "/" ++ H) =:= true], %%please note the "/" is added here
    %%io:format("Path: ~p, A: ~p~n", [Path, A]), 
    case A of
        [] ->   %%Base case, i.e. folder has no sub-folders -> stop here
                {PATH, []}; 
         _ ->   %%Recursive case, i.e. folder has sub-folders -> call @folders
                {PATH, [folders(PATH ++ "/" ++ H2) || H2 <- A]}
    end.

pretty_print(Folders, Depth) ->
    {CurrrentFolder, ListSubfolders} = Folders,
    SignTemp = lists:duplicate(Depth, "-"),
    case Depth of
        0 -> Sign = SignTemp;
        _ -> Sign = "|" ++ SignTemp
    end,
    io:format("~s~s~n", [Sign, CurrrentFolder]),
    [pretty_print(Subfolder, Depth+1) || Subfolder <- ListSubfolders].
```